# Why do my quotes give a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, linux, atom-editor, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint on my laptop for programming purposes.
The problem that I have is that, for some reason, double quotes or even single quotes do not work in my JavaScript code. The console in chrome returns a Syntax Error. Why does this happen?
Below you can find 2 pictures with a screenshot of the script and the error.

[image: script]
[image: console]

I am using Linux Mint as the Operating System, Atom as the editor and Google Chrome as the web browser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your keyboard input method. Maybe you are using different type of input.

Comment: Because those are fancy (curly) quotes, like this: `“Testing”`. You need straight quotes, like this: `"Testing"`. As @ShanilFernando said, check your keyboard settings. `"` is character code 34 (0x22). (You'll also want `'`, the straight apostrophe, which is character code 39 [0x27].)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Where do I change these settings? I switched to Linux today, so I am still a newbie.

Comment: @JonathanLagenhorst: It'll vary by distro and language. It happens I also use Linux Mint, and in my language (UK English) the quotes are already correct. If you go to Preferences | Keyboard and click the Layouts tab, you should find something, but I'm afraid I don't know that part well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried it and fixed it. Thank you. I changed my language from English (Us with dead keys) to English (US). There was probably something wrong with the dead keys method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see,

[image]

To change Keyboard input in Linux mint

```
Menu > Keyboard Preferences > Layouts > Add
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer.